# 2sxc: While trying to edit 2sxc content under site (other then Localhost:80), the content editor returns an empty window - Am I doing anything worng?

Tags: 2sxc

Two things:

First:
I've tried adding second host on my local IIS (v7.5 / Windows 7 / 64Bit / 16GB ram) for testing some content on my DNN site, but after adding, some thing of the 2sxc framework does not work, e.g. trying to edit something like query, gives me an empty explorer window.

Problem Description / steps:

1. Crated a (kind of) Announcements 2sxc app (basically as the "News - Simple" one from the site) -- OK
2. Added a List -- OK
3. Added fields to list -- OK
4. Added new (empty) views - as preparation for later -- OK
5. Added List items (2 for testing) -- OK
6. Created Query (one for list and one for details) -- OK

Now here is where I'm stuck:
 8. Trying to edit query (as shown in the "News - Simple" demo) and... Nothing, A new explorer tab comes up -- empty...

At this point, I've tried multiple things with no success:
 1. Directory Permissions
 2. Reinstalling 2sxc (versions 8.4, 8.4.8, 8.5) 
And a few more I cant recall now...

Second (actually a bug report for v8.5):
The description of a field on a list is not being saved, all the other values are fine, all but the description...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that something isn't right in your dnn paths. The content-editor dialog is technically a static HTML document (so it's called directly, no DNN aspx code executed). If you see a blank page, then either

1. the edit-page isn't shown
2. the edit page is shown, but something like the JavaScript isn't delivering data

Please turn on fiddler or F12 in your browser to see if you're getting 404 errors or similar. I'm almost certain that you'll then find a path being called which is wrong, because of dnn config.

Comment: Hello, iJungleBoy.

First, Thanks for the response.
Second, I'll check as  you recommended upon next time I'll start the second IIS.

BTW, It was all happening on a **_fresh_** install...

Comment: @DMagician what's a forced vacation :) - is that like getting pregnant unexpectedly and needing time to cope? love from Switzerland xo

Comment: First, "Forced vacation" meaning my workplace us having some cutbacks... :-(  
Second, because of (1), I will not test this because of time limitations...  
Third, unrelated to any, is there a possibility for forcefully showing the overloaded menu for add/edit/new... left-to-right and left aligned in a <div style='...direction: rtl;...'>rtl content </div>?

Comment: Bummer about (1) :( - but I didn't understand the other question.

Comment: I'm having a `<div>` with style containing `direction: rtl`, now, the floating add/edit/remove/publish is aligned to the right, and the buttons order is, from RIGHT to LEFT, add, edit and more, I want these buttons to be LEFT aligned and the buttons order from LEFT to RIGHT. (If only i knew how to attach an image...)

Comment: @ DMagician - I'm sure we can help you. Please create a new question though. And try just pasting the image, I think that works...